# No Console messages in Android Studio with Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

I'm using the emulator that comes with android studio to test my app. Usually if I use my phone to test it I can get all kinds of console messages and logcat. However, with the emulator I get no further messages after the ones seen in the screenshot.

[image]

How can I change it so that I see all the console messages that the app is producing?

I use the following method to output personal console messages. This doesn't work when I use the emulator.

Log.d("MapString", "TextFile: " + textContents);

I'm going to take a guess and say it has something to do with dubugging but I can't say for sure... please help!

Comment: The process you want to monitor is dead, so it can't log

Comment: Is your app able to start at all? It says your Google Play Services are outdated.

Comment: The lower right hand corner of Android Studio indicates there this an update. Update your Emulator System images in the SDK Manager to get the latest version of Google Play Services.  Once you are updated, you can also create a fresh new Android Virtual Device in the AVD Manager using API 25.  (https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html#createavd )